# Special characters in filter

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access database for managing trainings of employees. There are 2 cases which are causing trouble and for one I didn't find the solution yet.

Case 1: the training name contains `C++`

Case 2: it is a group training, in which case the employee is denoted as `*` for *everyone*

When I open the database, I can apply a filter in the column headings, but it does not filter correctly. My guess is that special characters need to be escaped.

I tried:

- select one of the entries via the checkbox
- use a text filter that sais "contains ..." with various escaping like below
- use `\` as the escape character
- use `[`...`]` as the escape character (suggestion in a forum), perhaps going back to the [LIKE operator](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931). This works for the `*` part but does not work for the `C++` part
- using `C??` , but that also matches terms like `advanced`
- building a form for the table and then filtering in the form
- Adding a breakpoint and looking at the resulting filters. I see that the `+` splits the query, so I also tried using `C[++][++]`

How do I filter a table for entries containing a `+`?

I'm using Access 2016. Please note that the `+` is in the data, not in the table name or in the column name.

Comment: Do not open the table. Create and open a form in table view - it has a Filter property which can easily accept values you need. Of course if you use LIKE operator in a Form.Filter value you must quote special chars as in a query.

Comment: @Akina: I created a form now, but it has the same issue

Comment: Open the form in Design mode. Open its code. Create Form_ApplyFilter method, add Stop operator into it. Switch form to View mode. Apply filter you need (with the value(s) which contains char(s) caused problems). When execution stops, open Locals windows and look for Me.Filter value which contains the char(s) you need and is correct.

Comment: @Akina: ok, I created that method and added a breakpoint. The value of `Me.Filter` is `"*C"+"+*"` when I just type `C++`. The filter value is `"C["+"]["+"]*"` when I type `C[+][+]`. It seems that the plus sign always stays a plus sign, no matter what.